# Splice box - how to use "polaris" connectors?

Tags: electrical, aluminum-wiring, splicing, splices

In the process to perform a DIY 400A main panel upgrade,

I have spliced these wires coming from the new main panel to a cable that goes to a sub-panel. This is a pre-existing box where the same cable was spliced to a different one going to my old main panel. The old cable has been removed.

[image: Splice box]

I used "polaris" connectors that were very expensive - more than 100 dollars for the three pictured above. Here a detail view:

[image: Polaris ITG3/0]

1. Are these connectors rated for 1/0 aluminum wire? There is NO gel inside the holes nor any marking that suggests it
2. I looked online and it was surprisingly difficult to find a torque for these. Best I found is 250in*lbs that sounds pretty high for a 3/16 hex driver
3. Is it OK to ground the box with that copper wire?

Comment: Ilsco PBTS is comparable to the Polaris ITG, but often priced 40% lower and also dual AL/CU rated (at least the one I checked was). And 250 in-lbs isn't so much - maybe you're thinking of ft-lbs? 250 in-lbs = 21 ft-lbs. You can see why connectors tightened to "that feels good" are often under-torqued.

Comment: A hex key bolt with 3/16 driver is typically a 1/4" threaded bolt size, which (for a grade 5 steel) typically takes 11ft*lbs. I am not sure if this threads into steel or aluminum, in any case a torque of over 20ft*lbs seems high to me. Maybe this screw is actually bigger than 1/4" but in my main panel, a screw that takes a much bigger 3/8" hex driver has a listed torque of 250in*lbs

Answer (score 3):

### Those are the wrong connectors

Note the "CU9" labeling by itself on the connectors you have -- this means that they are rated for copper and copper only.  You need to get connectors rated CU9AL instead, as that means they're rated for both copper and aluminum.

Comment: Oh man this is not the first time the local big electrical distributor gives me something that should work but it's not right, and then they charge 30% restock fee. I remember asking about polaris connectors able to splice 1/0 and 2/0 wire but I may not have specified aluminum, because who uses such big copper wires? :( :( :(

Comment: Is it OK to use that ground connection for the box?

Comment: @AlessioSangalli as to the ground wire, what size is that jumper down to the box?

Comment: I recycled a piece of 12ga wire pulled out of a scrap romex

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- yeah, that's far too small for bonding a box like that

Comment: excuse me but I had no idea, I have scrap 4 gauge, but how do I ground it to a 10-32 screw? It seems I totally underestimated the box grounding task. I also used the same 12ga for another similar box, I'll have to re-do everything! Surely I cannot just twist some 4ga aluminum around a small screw however...

Comment: @AlessioSangalli use a 14-4 Al/Cu single wire lug with a #10 hole in it, such as a Brumall 6T or equivalent

Comment: Do you have a reference to the code that governs grounding/bonding of splice boxes of this size? Everything I find on the WWW is about boxes for light switches :(

Comment: @AlessioSangalli NEC 250.86 & 250.148(C) are your friends here

Comment: I went back at the electrical distributor and I spoke to somebody that immediately understood I needed the aluminum rated polaris'. Funny thing, the dual Cu/Al rated are actually *cheaper* than the Cu-only ones. They did not charge a restock fee.

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- the Cu-only ones exist to handle fine-stranded wires (such as welding cable)

Comment: I am starting to doubt the split bolt can connect three wires now.